# android camera preview out of screen

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I am having problem with my app camera preview.

**Default camera app:**
When I look at preview from default camera and its taken picture. Default preview shows a half less from top and bottom side.

**My camera app preview:**
It only shows everything on top side. So after you take picture, its center is in totally  different place (from the takers perspective, even if the end picture is the same).

**Goal:**
I want my app preview to work the same as default app preview.

I took code from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic
so mine is almost the same.
Any tip on how achieve this or link to explanation would be greatly appreciated!

[Compare preview my App vs Default app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPd1u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Soulution**:(it will only make sense if you are looking at  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

In method configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight). Move your preview by mTextureView.Y();

by how much you get from (mTextureView.getHeight - displaySizeHeight);